# The vertical scrollbar keeps disapearing on my DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

We're building a Windows application in Visual Studio C# 2008 Express Edition, returning a data set from our server and displaying it in a DataGridView. Certain users are complaining that the vertical scroll bar keeps vanishing when they're working. They can restore it by closing down that screen and re-opening it.

We're struggling to debug this problem because it doesn't happen all the time and never happens to some users (including all of our developers).

When the scrollbar has vanished, it leaves the space that it occupied, but instead of displaying the control, we get a graduated blue colour (which looks very much line the backdrop of the screen at that point).

My initial feeling is that this could be a bug in the DataGridView control. Have any of you encountered such an error before? Can you offer any sugestions on where to start fixing it?

The code that we're running is:
My collegue (who's developing this screen) has provided the following code for you: // // dGridJournal // this.dGridJournal.AllowUserToAddRows = false; this.dGridJournal.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false; this.dGridJournal.AllowUserToResizeRows = false; this.dGridJournal.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right))); this.dGridJournal.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft; dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control; dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))); dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText; dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight; dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True; this.dGridJournal.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1; this.dGridJournal.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize; this.dGridJournal.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] { this.jrnhidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.typedesc, this.pdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.narridDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.pvalueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.authdesc}); 
this.dGridJournal.DataCont = this.dataContJournalEnquiries; this.dGridJournal.DataSource = this.ttJRNHeaderBindingSource; dataGridViewCellStyle3.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft; dataGridViewCellStyle3.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window; dataGridViewCellStyle3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))); dataGridViewCellStyle3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight; dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText; dataGridViewCellStyle3.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False; this.dGridJournal.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle3; this.dGridJournal.LabelText = "Please enter mandatory criteria."; this.dGridJournal.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 4); this.dGridJournal.ModifiedCellColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown; this.dGridJournal.MultiSelect = false;
this.dGridJournal.Name = "dGridJournal"; this.dGridJournal.ReadOnly = true; dataGridViewCellStyle4.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft; dataGridViewCellStyle4.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control; dataGridViewCellStyle4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))); dataGridViewCellStyle4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText; dataGridViewCellStyle4.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle4.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText; dataGridViewCellStyle4.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True; this.dGridJournal.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle4; this.dGridJournal.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect; this.dGridJournal.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(488, 95); this.dGridJournal.TabIndex = 1; this.dGridJournal.TabStop = false; this.dGridJournal.UpScroll = true;
this.dGridJournal.SortStarted += new CapitaHartshead.Core.Controls.CHDataGridView.SortStartingHandler(this.dGridJournal_SortStarted); this.dGridJournal.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dGridJournal_SelectionChanged); // // jrnhidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn // this.jrnhidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader; this.jrnhidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "jrnhid"; this.jrnhidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Journal Number"; 
this.jrnhidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "jrnhidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"; this.jrnhidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true; this.jrnhidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 97; // // typedesc // this.typedesc.DataPropertyName = "typedesc"; this.typedesc.HeaderText = "Type"; this.typedesc.Name = "typedesc"; this.typedesc.ReadOnly = true; this.typedesc.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable; this.typedesc.Width = 55; // // pdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn // this.pdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "pdate";
this.pdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Date"; this.pdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "pdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"; this.pdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true; this.pdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 80; // // narridDataGridViewTextBoxColumn // this.narridDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill; this.narridDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "narr"; this.narridDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Description"; 
this.narridDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "narridDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"; this.narridDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true; this.narridDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable; // // pvalueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn // this.pvalueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "pvalue"; dataGridViewCellStyle2.Format = "C2"; dataGridViewCellStyle2.NullValue = null; this.pvalueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2; this.pvalueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Value"; 
this.pvalueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "pvalueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"; this.pvalueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true; this.pvalueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 80; // // authdesc // this.authdesc.DataPropertyName = "authdesc"; this.authdesc.HeaderText = "State"; this.authdesc.Name = "authdesc"; this.authdesc.ReadOnly = true; this.authdesc.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable; this.authdesc.Width = 50;

Comment: Can you post the code that Visual Studio generated in the Designer which creates the DataGridView?

Comment: It will be easier to read if you can add all the code in the comments to the main question and remove the comments. comments is not the place to add such lengthy code segments

Comment: Ah! Thanks for that user428468. I'm still trying to get to grips with Stack Overflow and how it should be used. I've moved the code as you sugested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a bit of digging around, we've been able to reliably replicate the problem. It appears to be connected to the timing of the screen being rendered. Once my collegue had identified that, he simply delayed the render slightly and that's solved the problem.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

We did try hiding and re-displaying the scroll bar, but this was unssuccessful.

We've also tried disabling the datagrid view while we update the data, then re-enabeling it once complete. We've not yet heard back whether this worked or not.